# Iterating through a Data Transfer Object inside the Web Method Call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, web-services

I am sending a DTO to a web service using JQuery, but i need to know how to iterate through the object when received at the web service call. Here is the code

### JQUERY

```
$(divButtonText).click(function() {

            var QuestionItems = {};
            var foundEmptyFields = false;
            var count = 1;
            $(".diverror").hide();

            $(".cmsquestions").each(function() {

                var question = $($(this).find(".cmstextbox input")).val();
                var radioValue = $($($('input[name="responsefields' + count + '"]:checked')).next()).text();

                if (question.length > 0) {

                    var questionnumber = $(".cmspagenumber").length;

                    if (questionnumber == 0) {

                        questionnumber = 1;
                    }

                    var QuestionItem = {};

                    QuestionItem.TitleID = data.d;
                    QuestionItem.Number = questionnumber;
                    QuestionItem.Question = question;
                    QuestionItem.FieldType = radioValue;

                    QuestionItems[count - 1] = QuestionItem;
                }
                else {
                    foundEmptyFields = true;
                    var error = $(this).find(".diverror");
                    $(error).show();
                }

                count += 1;

            });

            if (!foundEmptyFields) {



                var DTO = { 'QuestionItems': QuestionItems };
                var param = JSON.stringify(DTO);
                Ajax_WebService(param, 'AddQuestion', AddQuestionServerResponse);

            }

        });
```

### WEBMETHOD

```
 <WebMethod()> _
  Public Function AddQuestion(ByVal QuestionItems As Object) As Integer

    For i As Integer = 0 To QuestionItems.Count - 1



    Next


End Function
```

### EDIT

### WEB Service Call

```
function Ajax_WebService(param, method, callback) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CMSAdmin.asmx/" + method,
    data: param,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        if (callback) {
            callback.call(null, data);
        }

    }
});

}
```

### EDIT

Ok i have changed the WebMethod to this

```
 <WebMethod()> _
 Public Function AddQuestion(ByVal QuestionItems As List(Of QuestionItem)) As Integer




End Function
```

I can now possibly iterate through the list items but my QuestionItem class is picking up values of nothing and empty, the QuestionItem class is here

```
Public Class QuestionItem


    Private _TitleID As Integer
    Private _Number As Integer
    Private _Question As String
    Private _FieldType As String

    Public ReadOnly Property TitleID() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._TitleID
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Number() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._Number
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Question() As String
        Get
            If Me._Question Is Nothing Then
                Return String.Empty
            End If
            Return Me._Question
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property FieldType() As String
        Get
            If Me._FieldType Is Nothing Then
                Return String.Empty
            End If
            Return Me._FieldType
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Why is the properties returning null and empty values from the JSON Object, that class structure is the same as the JSON Class Structure?

Comment: The for loop in your code already is iterating.

Comment: amit_g: but i cant seem to get the values from the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the WebMethod call that uses QuestionItem Class to set the values from the JSON Request

```
<WebMethod()> _
 Public Function AddQuestion(ByVal QuestionItems() As QuestionItem) As Integer


    For Each item As QuestionItem In QuestionItems




    Next


End Function

Public Class QuestionItem


    Private _TitleID As Integer
    Private _Number As Integer
    Private _Question As String
    Private _FieldType As String

    Public Property TitleID() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._TitleID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me._TitleID = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Number() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me._Number
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me._Number = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Question() As String
        Get
            If Me._Question Is Nothing Then
                Return String.Empty
            End If
            Return Me._Question
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._Question = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property FieldType() As String
        Get
            If Me._FieldType Is Nothing Then
                Return String.Empty
            End If
            Return Me._FieldType
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me._FieldType = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

The Jquery and Javascript is below of how to format out the JSON Request client side

```
$(divButton).click(function() {

            var QuestionItems = new Array();

            var foundEmptyFields = false;
            var count = 1;
            $(".diverror").hide();

            $(".cmsquestions").each(function() {

                var question = $($(this).find(".cmstextbox input")).val();
                var radioValue = $($($('input[name="responsefields' + count + '"]:checked')).next()).text();

                if (question.length > 0) {

                    var questionnumber = $(".cmspagenumber").length;

                    if (questionnumber == 0) {

                        questionnumber = 1;
                    }

                    var QuestionItem = {};

                    QuestionItem.TitleID = data.d;
                    QuestionItem.Number = questionnumber;
                    QuestionItem.Question = question;
                    QuestionItem.FieldType = radioValue;

                    QuestionItems.push(QuestionItem);
                }
                else {
                    foundEmptyFields = true;
                    var error = $(this).find(".diverror");
                    $(error).show();
                }

                count += 1;

            });

            if (!foundEmptyFields) {



                var DTO = "{ 'QuestionItems':" + JSON.stringify(QuestionItems) + "}";
                var param = DTO;
                Ajax_WebService(param, 'AddQuestion', AddQuestionServerResponse);

            }

        });


function Ajax_WebService(param, method, callback) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CMSAdmin.asmx/" + method,
    data: param,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        if (callback) {
            callback.call(null, data);
        }

    }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize` method to convert incoming string to a type that matches your `QuestionItem` collection; then loop.

Comment: But the data im passing to the webservice is an object, can i deserialize the object some how?

Comment: Change the webmethod arg to string, as the incoming type is string (you are doing `JSON.stringify(DTO);`, which is correct, btw). `QuestionItems As Object` can be casted to string.

Comment: i have tried changing to string and still no luck, and i tried casting the object to string and that doesn't work i am afraid

Comment: Any errors? Or what are you getting that string value to be (paste at least a snippet).

Comment: no errors, just that the web service isnt being called when you change the object to string datatype

Comment: I have edited my question and i think i am getting closer, just need some help once more